# How to open javascript developer console from SAP HTML Viewer

Tags: html, abap, developer-console

We have a custom web application that gets used via normal desktop browser, including IE, Chrome, and Firefox. When troubleshooting javascript type issues with this application, we can use the F12 button to open the javascript developer console.

This web application is also referenced inside of SAP GUI via the HTML Viewer.

The trouble that we have is that clicking F12 does not open the javascript developer console for us. Does anyone know how we go about opening this javascript developer console for a web application within SAP GUI HTML Viewer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using newer versions of windows, you might want to give `F12Chooser.exe` a try. It's the same developer console you would get from hitting F12 on IE, but it gives you the ability to choose a target to debug.

You can find the exe at `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F12\F12Chooser.exe` (change `SysWOW64` by `System32` if you're on a 32bit machine)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: On my 64 bit PC with Windows 10, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F12\F12Chooser.exe displayed the list of targets, but clicking the "saplogon" target froze the F12 chooser. But using the System32 version worked like a charm.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Just a note, on my system it's under `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F12\IEChooser.exe`